# How do I calculate the barycentric position of the sun at a given julian date?

Tags: the-sun

I have used the (matlab/octave) SOFA routine/function iauEpv00 to get the barycentric position and velocity of the Earth, but now need to find barycentric position of the sun. Can't seem to find the right routine/function.

Comment: This is unhelpful, but I, myself, would use SPICE: http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html

Comment: Thanks for replying Barry. I have thought of that, but I'm using Octave in Windows. There is a special port of the SPICE functions into Matlab called MICE. To use MICE in Linux you have to do some compiling (see [link](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/MATLAB/req/mice.html#Use%20of%20Mice%20with%20Octave).  I have no idea how to get MICE to work in Octave/Windows.

Comment: I am hoping that I've missed a simple program, maybe in SOFA, that can be used, like iauEpv00 for the earth, which works well.

Comment: Since iauEpv00 gives both the heliocentric and barycentric position of Earth, you could subtract the two to find the barycentric position of the Sun?

Comment: Barry, you're right! Thanks. Still a lot to learn.